# Swift Converting CGMutablePath to MKPolygon

Tags: swift, swift3, mapkit

I have ann app which will allow users to draw in their own geofences. Right now the way that it works is the user draws their geofence on the screen and the app is keeping track of where they are drawing and storing their path into a CGMutablePath.

My question is how can I take this CGMutablePath and apply it to a MKPolygon so that the users hand drawn geofence can be applied as a Map overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use your points from the user's touches to build an `MKOverlay`:

```
let coords = points.map({ CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double($0.x), longitude: Double($0.y)) })
let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: coords, count: coords.count)
```

You might need to also take into account the current zoom level of the map to make sure the conversion between points on the screen and lat/lng is correct.

Next, you can add this overlay to the map:

```
mapView.add(overlay)
```

To style the overlay (change its color, etc), use the `MKMapViewDelegate` method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue
    return renderer
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have the code set up, but it doesn't work. I think it's because the coordinates from the users touches need to be converted to actual latitude/longitude points. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You can use `MKMapView`'s `convert(_:toCoordinateFrom:)` function, which should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can I take this CGMutablePath and apply it to a MKPolygon

You don't. If what you have is a general CGPath, use a custom MKOverlay along with MKOverlayPathRenderer.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Can you please give more details or point me in the right direction? I'm not familiar with making a custom MKOverlay, would I be able to pass my CGPath to the custom MKOverlay?

Comment: Exactly. That's what the custom MKOverlay is for. You need a way to carry the path to the MKOverlayPathRenderer; your MKOverlay does that job, because you've cleverly given it a path property. Thus, when you get to `mapView(_:rendererFor:)`, you can pull the path out of the MKOverlay and use it to set the MKOverlayPathRenderer's path.